# Drop down and radio button click events

Tags: jquery

I need to implement some jquery validations to a pop up. User first select drop down and then check radio button. Only after that the submit button is enabled. Now I need to implement same action for opposite direction. User first check radio and then select drop down item. I have developed code for first scenario. How to modify this code to work for both ways?

```
   $(".dropdown-menu-popup").on('change', function (){ 
        $('.feedback-selector').on('click', function() { 
            var selected_value =  $( ".dropdown-menu-popup option:selected" ).val(); 
            if(selected_value.localeCompare("0")==0){
                $("#submit_feedback").css('background-color', '#ddd');
            }else if(selected_value.localeCompare("site_nav")==0 || selected_value.localeCompare("site_cont")==0 || selected_value.localeCompare("site_design")==0 || selected_value.localeCompare("other")==0 && $(".feedback-selector").is(':checked')){

            $("#submit_feedback").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#submit_feedback").css({
              'border' : 'none',
              'color' : '#fff !important',
              'background-color': '#f4901d',
              'cursor' : 'pointer'
            });
            }
         });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this


 $(".dropdown-menu-popup, .feedback-selector").change(function (){ 
                    var selected_value =  $( ".dropdown-menu-popup option:selected" ).val(); 
                    if(selected_value.localeCompare("0")==0){
                        $("#submit_feedback").css('background-color', '#ddd');
                    }else if(selected_value.localeCompare("site_nav")==0 || selected_value.localeCompare("site_cont")==0 || selected_value.localeCompare("site_design")==0 || selected_value.localeCompare("other")==0 && $(".feedback-selector").is(':checked')){

                    $("#submit_feedback").prop('disabled', false);
                    $("#submit_feedback").css({
                      'border' : 'none',
                      'color' : '#fff !important',
                      'background-color': '#f4901d',
                      'cursor' : 'pointer'
                    });
                }
           });
```

Comment: If it works! Please mark as answered. So that it will be helpful for others as well.